# Woocommerce - Create custom cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

On my checkout page I added a custom field `imei` that receives a value from the `url`:

```
mydomain.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=141&imei=123456789456123
```

This works fine but if I don't proceed to checkout and leave the page or close the browser, the value of the field is lost so I need to find a way to save this value until I successfully complete the checkout.

I was thinking of using cookies for this but there isn't much info on how to do this with woocommerce.

Any idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the PHP setcookie() function.

To set the cookie:

```
if ( isset ( $_GET['imei'] ) ){
    $cookie_name = 'imei';
    $cookie_value = $_GET['imei']; // You should check/validate this value for security
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

To use the cookie:

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] ) ){
    echo 'Cookie named "' . $cookie_name . '" is set and its value is:' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help ;-)